# Can't run ffmpeg on OSMC

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, apt, osmc

I have an OSMC system with Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). I can't run ffmpeg:

```
osmc@osmc:~$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Apparently, there's no problem with the installed packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
$ dpkg -C # no output
```

I tried reinstalling ffmpeg:

```
$ sudo apt-get reinstall ffmpeg
```

I also tried remove/install (reinstalls 87 packages):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

I read that one of the packages `libglu1` or `libgl1` would help.

- installing `libglu1` did not help.
- apt says it would remove `rbp2-device-osmc`, `rbp2-mediacenter-osmc` and `rbp2-mesa-osmc` for installing `libgl1` so I didn't try.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The file missing `libGL.so.1` is provided by the [libgl1](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libgl1) package. It is conflicted with another package that is accidentally provided by OSMC: [libglapi-mesa](https://packages.debian.org/de/buster/libglapi-mesa).

The solution:

```
echo 'deb http://apt.osmc.tv bullseye-devel main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/osmc-devel.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && reboot
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa
```